# Can I create a scordcard with a percentage change in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm new to PowerBI.
I wanted to create a scorecard that looks like the one in data studio where it displays the total value and percentage change from the previous period.

Below is the screenshot from Google Studio

[image: Google Datastudio scorecard]

Answer (score 0):

You can add % from the data view in powerbi desktop,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

PowerBI has some learning curve compare to Google Studio. I would recommend you to explore more and get yourself comfortable and try to find answers yourself.

But you should be able to achieve the output you're expecting using measures. Measures are similar to excel formula that allow you to calculate from existing values.

checkout the following resources:

- [Show Growth Value and Percentage in one Power BI Card visual](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xw_NL8jDMN4)
- [How to show percentage change in Bar chart visual in Power BI](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-show-percentage-change-in-Bar-chart-visual-in-Power-BI/td-p/991156)